# Django + HTMX: Search Form is not removing trailing spaces despite strip=True & even if strip() is called in view

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-forms, htmx

For some odd reason, my form is not being cleaned when hx-POSTing to /word-search/. This is causing the search to not return results despite it actually existing in the db.

Form:

```
class WordSearchForm(forms.Form):
    word_search = forms.CharField(
        strip=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'hx-post': '/word-search/',
                'hx-target': '#results',
                'hx-trigger': 'keyup changed delay:500ms',
                'placeholder': 'Search by word...'
            }
        )
    )
```

View:

```
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def word_search(request):

    if request.META.get('HTTP_HX_REQUEST'):

        results = None
        search_text = request.POST.get('word_search', None)

        print(search_text.endswith(' ')) => True

        if search_text is not None:

            ...

            word = search_text.strip() -> Even this does not work
            sentences = KWord.objects.filter(word__word=word)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [Django Forms interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view), so Django cannot apply the filtering functions. You have to validate the form via calling `form.is_valid()`. The validated data will be in `form.cleaned_data`.

```
if request.META.get('HTTP_HX_REQUEST'):
    form = WordSearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Now strip has been applied to `word_search` field
        search_text = form.cleaned_data['word_search']
        ...
```

On the second issue: check the `filter(word__word=word)` filter. The `__word` [field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) does not exists, so I guess the HTMX request throws a 500 internal server error, but you don't have error handling on the frontend to see it. Maybe you want to make a [`word__contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains) filtering.